# SQL: Add multiple rows from one table to another when no data for that date in new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update medical data from one table to another after switching from one system to another. We have two tables, for simplicity I'll make this a simple example. There are many columns in these tables in reality (not just 5).

**Table1**:

```
name, date, var1, var2, var3
```

**Table2**:

```
name, date, var1a, var2a, var3a
```

I want to transfer data from Table 1 to Table 2 for any rows where there isn't previous data for that date, where var1 = var1a, etc (same columns with different names).

I was trying to do something with a loop, but realized that may not be necessary.

I had gotten this far but keep wasn't sure if this was ok:

```
UPDATE Table2 VALUES (date, var1a, var2a, var3a)
SELECT date, var1, var2, var3 FROM Table1
```

Is that correct syntax so far?  Or do I need to map the variables to translate var1 into var1a, etc?

How do I add a check to make sure I don't overwrite any data already in Table1?  I don't want to add data if there is already data for that date/name combination.

Thanks!

Comment: `update` has no `values` clause - check the manual of your DBMS the `update` and `insert` statements are full documented there.

Comment: Thanks - so if I change "Update" above to "Insert INTO" is that otherwise correct?

Comment: `insert ... select` has no values clause (which is all documented in the maual). Which DBMS are you using anyway? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 specifically

Comment: "SQL" is not a DBMS, it's a query language. Postgres uses SQL, Oracle uses SQL, DB2 uses SQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `INSERT` into `TABLE2` all values from `TABLE1` that do not already exist in `Table2`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (date, var1a, var2a, var3a)
SELECT date, var1, var2, var3 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.date = t1.date)
```

Already existing values are specified by comparing the `date` column. You can add any other predicates in the `SELECT` subquery of the `NOT EXISTS` expression to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `update with a join`. And you dont need to update the `date column` since that's what you are using to find the matches in the 2 tables.

Either you generate a dynamic query based on the empty/null valued columns, or you could do something like the below, which puts the same value in the column if it exists in `table2` or else puts the corresponding value from `table1`. 
The below approach requires less logic and easier to implement but will produce IO equivalent to updating the entire table.

```
update tbl2
set val1a=isnull(val1a,val1)
, val2a=isnull(val2a,val2)
, val3a=isnull(val3a.val3)
from table1 tbl1
inner join table2 tbl2 
on tbl1.name=tbl2.name
and tbl1.date=tbl2.date
```

Considerations:

The approach requires less logic and easier to implement but will produce IOs equivalent to updating the entire table2. If you have a smallish table i would go with this approach.

If its a big table then you should look into building specific query sets to reduce IO

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually not joining it by the date column however.  I'm adding data when there ISN'T a corresponding date in table2.  If there already is data for that date, I'll skip that entry in table1

Comment: So if table2 has 2 rows like name('xyz'), date(null), var1a('a'), var2a('b'), var3a('c') and name('xyz1'), date(null), var1a('a1'), var2a('b1'), var3a('c1'). How will you map these rows to table1 without the date field?

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested in Access but something very similar should work in SQL Server 2012:

```
UPDATE Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.date = Table1.date 
SET Table2.name = Table1.name, Table2.date = Table1.date, Table2.var1 = Table1.var1a, Table2.var2 = Table1.var2a, Table2.var3 = Table1.var3a
WHERE (Table2.date Is Null);
```

Explanation: this uses a right join so that within the query all the data from Table1 is present and where there is a matched date for Table2 that data is present too. We then ignore all cases where there is any data for Table2 and update the query in all other cases - the update in fact inserts new data into Table2.